# Compile *.a to *.so

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

Maybe a stupid title, but I was not creative enough to find a better one.
My Problem:
I have a dynamic library that contains my core library and a guy library FoxToolkit
So the *.so file contains, as sampl,  mycorelib.a and foxtoolkit.a
I have now removed all depencies to foxtoolkit.a from mycorelib.a and so foxtoolkit is obsolete.
So I just need the mycorelib.a as a dynamic library mycorelib.so

What is needed, maybe a commandline for gcc, to make the .a to .so?

Answer (score 1):

There multiple ways to achieve this.

First, because `.a` is an archive, you can unpack it and create a shared library from `.o` files

```
ar -x mycorelib.a
g++ -shared *.o -o mycorelib.so
```

Second, is just a oneliner that does the same, but needs a bit more effort to understand

```
gcc -shared -o mycorelib.so -Wl,--whole-archive mycorelib.a
```